# React Components and overriding Twitter Bootstrap styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I am currently using reactjs and twitter bootstrap (for styles). I am also using the CSSModules library found [HERE](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) in order to allow for an external style sheet. I have been able to get none bootstrap components to style correctly, but I am struggling with overriding Twitter-bootstrap styles with my own custom CSS. More specifically, I am not able to override the navbar-inverse class with my own styles. My goal is to change the background color to white, and the link text color to black. the code below focuses on just changing the background color, but nothing happens with any variation I can think of. Has anyone figured out the correct way to override twitter bootstrap styles for react components? Your help would be greatly appreciated!

If you have any questions or concerns, please just let me know.

Here is the HTML

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" styleName="navbar-custom">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#Home" activeClassName="active"> Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#OurMission" activeClassName="active"> Our Mission </a></li>
                            <li><a href="#Projects" activeClassName="active">Projects </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
```

and there is the CSS from styles.css

```
.navbar-custom{
   background-color: #ffffff!important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for "className" attribute instead of "styleName". And, you should change all your "class" attributes to "className", otherwise React will throw warnings while parsing your dom.

Comment: Hey! thanks for the reply. I'm using a webpack.config that allows for "class", and styleName is the naming convention used for this CSSModule library ( https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules#whats-the-problem )  to pick up my custom CSS, and link it back to the external stylesheet I'm using.

Comment: I see. So you're able to set any other CSS styles just fine? Its just overriding Bootstrap that's not working? And you can see .navbar-custom class applied to the element in developer tools?

Comment: I think I just figured out the issue. per your suggestion, I checked the element a bit closer in the inspector. It seems the background wasnt changing because (for reasons I dont understand) Twitter Bootstrap also adds a gradient background image. Once I performed an override specifically for background-image, the override worked. 

To be blunt, nothing was ever wrong, I am just dumb and didnt think to thoroughly check the inspector for the correct class to be overriding. I do thank you @nuway for your help, as you pointed me in the right direction.